# Wildcard in italic text (github markdown)

Tags: github, markdown

How can I put text in italic, and have a wildcard character in it?

I have tried

```
*something\*something*
```

but it doesn't seem to work on github (though it works on SO?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly, Github's Gist service renders this like you want

```
*file**.*dat*
```

but GitHub proper doesn't.

In a GitHub `README.md` you can use HTML entities to put an asterisk in the middle of an italicised word:

```
*file&#42;.dat*
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me:
    \*xxx\*.xxx\* shows up with the first x's in italic then whats after the dot is regular with a stray wildcard at the end... \*xxx\\*xxx\* doesn't work either

Comment: @user2711115, ah, you have a period adjacent to an asterisk. That wasn't in your question. It *does* work with `*something*something*`, but the period acts as a word-separator, which makes it not work. What, exactly, are you trying to accomplish (instead of "something" or "xxx", tell us what your real content is).

Comment: Well it's a filename im trying to show in italic with a wildcard in the name (just before the file extension), there's file1.dat, file2.dat etc and I'm trying to show file\*.dat in italic

Comment: damn it still doesn't work, can't believe it's that complicated for such a simple thing :o

Comment: The full thing I want is "(file\*.dat and file\*.dat*)" could the parentheses also affect the formatting?

Comment: @user2711115, should that last asterisk be there (`file*.dat*`)? And how much of that phrase in parentheses should be italicised? Just the file patterns, or the entire thing with "and" as well?

Comment: ops sorry no last asterisk (can't edit), and just the files should be in italic

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68570/discussion-between-chris-and-user2711115).